# iTunes Home Sharing: Shares Entire Library Instead of Selected Playlists

Tags: itunes, network, sharing

I have my master iTunes library on a Mac Mini, and I set up Home Sharing to stream my music and videos to my MacBook Pro.  When I had iTunes 9, I selected certain playlists to share and not others, and things worked fine.  When I upgraded to iTunes 10, now the entire library shows up on the MacBook Pro.  But I still only want the selected playlists.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I've gone into Preferences and double-checked that I'm only sharing selected playlists.
- I've quit iTunes on both machines and re-launched it.
- I've turned off Home Sharing on both machines, then turned it back on.
- I've switched the setting on the Mac Mini to "Share my entire library", applied the change, then switched it back to "Share selected playlists" and applied the change.
- I've right-clicked different playlists on the Mac Mini and verified that Share is unchecked when desired.  But it still shows up on the MacBook Pro

I'm using iTunes 10.2.1, so it's the current version.

So: how can I convince iTunes on the Mac Mini not to share only the playlists I've selected?

Answer (score 2):

Confusingly, the Sharing preferences have no effect on Home Sharing, which is a separate sharing mechanism altogether.

The main advantage of Home Sharing is that it allows copying from one Library to another; the disadvantage is that as yet, you don't get to control which playlists are shared.

Comment: You're right, that is confusing indeed. What do the "Sharing" preferences affect, if not Home Sharing?

Comment: They affect the library sharing, which you have to turn on to access those settings but not to use home sharing. Library sharing allows anyone on the same network to see your music, but home sharing allows only people with your apple id and password to see it.